# Python selenium selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:

Tags: python, selenium

I have this weird error with selenium when I try to find sportsbook odds from oddsportal.com. It looks like selenium object does not work like a normal list and I can not just loop over every url. Test url that should work http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/ (Script is not written for home-draw-away odds).

So what am I doing wrong here?
My script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchAttributeException,NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class Odds():
    def odds(self,driver,url):

        kertoimet = ['','']
        driver.get(url)
        odds = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="odds-data table"]/div/table/tbody/tr""")
        for item in odds:
            data = item.text.replace(' ','').split('\n')
            if data[0] == 'Pinnacle':
                kertoimet = [data[1],data[2]]
        return kertoimet

    def odds_finder(self,data,driver):

        for item in data:
            if item.get_attribute('href') != '':
                print(Odds().odds(driver,str(item.get_attribute('href'))))

    def url_finder2(self,URL):

        driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver 2")

        driver.get(URL) #http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/
        data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="tournamentTable"]/tbody/tr/td/a""")

        Odds().odds_finder(list(data),driver)

Odds().url_finder2(URL)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "odds.py", line 79, in <module>
Odds().url_finder2(open('oddsportal_odds.csv'))
File "odds.py", line 61, in url_finder2
Odds().odds_finder(list(data),driver)
File "odds.py", line 49, in odds_finder
if item.get_attribute('href') != '':
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 141, in 
get_attribute
resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in 
_execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: 
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 
(0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.3 
x86_64)
```

Comment: Why your xpath is quoted between `" " "`?

Comment: Every tutorial says that its better to put the xpath that way. I know its kinda useless here.

Comment: You can refer [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) official document and try the below solution. May be it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `data` again because the state gets changed.

Try modifying this 2 function.

```
def odds_finder(self,driver):
        for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="tournamentTable"]/tbody/tr/td/a"):
            time.sleep(5)
            if item.get_attribute('href') != '':
                print(Odds().odds(driver, str(item.get_attribute('href'))))

def url_finder2(self, URL):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver 2")
    driver.get(URL)  # http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/
    Odds().odds_finder(driver)
```

Comment: Same error. It does not want to go through every match.